# Get points in Cimplicity using Visual Basic script engine

Tags: vb.net, dynamic-variables

I would like to get the values from points that i have connected from control system, using basic script engine. The problem is there are many points, so i want to build a somewhat loop like below :

```
For i As New Points = 0 To 70
     Dim Para + i  AS OracleParameter
    PointGet("SST(i)_H_MTR")

Next i
```

instead of doing this :

```
dim SST01 as New Points
dim SST02 as New Points
dim SST03 as New Points

pointget(SST01_H_MTR)
pointget(SST02_H_MTR)
pointget(SST03_H_MTR)
```

the problem is, the points can not be defined as an array. Would somebody have found same problem with me ? any open idea is very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here you go.

```
Dim ptMTR as New Point
Dim pointName as String
Dim pointType as String
Dim MTR_Value as Integer
Dim i as Integer

pointType = "_H_MTR"

For i = 0 To 70
   if i < 10 then
     pointName = "SST0"
   else
     pointName = "SST"
   end if

   ptMTR.Id = pointName + cstr(i) + pointType
   MTR_Value = ptMTR.GetValue

  'Write code to use the point value here

  'Go get the next point value

next i
...
```